# How can I Align my Text with item numbering in Latex?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, numbering, paragraphs

Can you please look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong?
I am new to latex and trying to make an assignment. I believe I have gotten the commands I need to get the document except that when I compile the document, the texts indication the question number, that is "QUESTION 1" and "QUESTION TWO" DO NOT align in a perfect line with the numbered items on my page two (2). Please help.

```
\documentclass{article} \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\alph{enumi})}
\newcommand{\np}{\newpage}
\usepackage[margin=3.5cm]{geometry}
```

## This is page 1

```
\begin{document} 
\title{DOCUMENT TITLE}    
\author{\textbf{\Large MY NAME}\\[3mm]  
    \textbf{\Large MY NUMBER}}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\np
```

## This is page 2

```
\textbf{Question 1}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
  \begin{verbatim}
  M<-matrix(c(1,3,5,2,4,6), nrow=3, ncol=2, byrow=FALSE)
  \end{verbatim} 
\item     
  \begin{verbatim}
  attach(Personnel)
  Salary<-round(Salary,2)
  \end{verbatim}
\end{enumerate}
\textbf{Question 2}
\end{document}
```

PS: I have tried the `\align` command but it doesn't work.

**Output**

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com)! for the image on the edit panel clic on the icon containing a montain. also put the links for question you mentionned please

Answer (score 4):

I think this is waht you want, obtained with the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\newcommand{\np}{\newpage}
\usepackage[margin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\title{DOCUMENT TITLE}
\author{\textbf{\Large MY NAME}\\[3mm]
    \textbf{\Large MY NUMBER}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\np

\textbf{Question 1}
\begin{enumerate}[wide, label=(\alph*), leftmargin =*]
\item
  \begin{verbatim}
  M<-matrix(c(1,3,5,2,4,6), nrow=3, ncol=2, byrow=FALSE)
  \end{verbatim}
\item
  \begin{verbatim}
  attach(Personnel)
  Salary<-round(Salary,2)
  \end{verbatim}
\end{enumerate}

\textbf{Question 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\alph{enumi})}` is not needed, of course.

Comment: @egreg: Oops! I posted  previous version. Thanks for pointing it. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Your “Question 1” is indented and you probably don't want it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\question}[1]{%
  \par\noindent\textbf{Question #1}\par
}

\begin{document}

\question{1}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*), leftmargin =*,align=left]
\item
\begin{verbatim}
M<-matrix(c(1,3,5,2,4,6), nrow=3, ncol=2, byrow=FALSE)
\end{verbatim}
\item
\begin{verbatim}
attach(Personnel)
Salary<-round(Salary,2)
\end{verbatim}
\end{enumerate}

\question{2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't indent `verbatim` environments, or the indentation in the typescript will pass to the output.

Don't use abbreviations like `\np` for `\newpage`; they are difficult to spot in the typescript. If you want to use `\newpage`, leave a blank line before and after it: you'll see it clearly when revising the document.